# How to add images dynamically from camera/UIImagePickerController to iCarousel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icarousel

I am using iCarousel as shownh [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) .But I want to add images dynamically by taking a pic from camera or imagepicker. following is my code,

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];
    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    // Initialize and configure the carousel
    carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, 100, 100)];
    carousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow;
    carousel.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:carousel];
}
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [imagesArray count];

}
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
    return  [imagesArray count];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UIImage *image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,100, 100)] autorelease];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag=index;
    return button;

}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [imagesArray addObject:image];
    NSLog(@"array count is %d",[imagesArray count]);
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Even I able to add the images to array , Only one image is appearing the imageView in coverflow.
Can Any one please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call reloadData on the carousel after modifying the array.

Comment: I have written [carousel reloadData] after [imagesArray addObject:image] statement.It worked for me..Thanks alot and very awsome tutorial..

Comment: - (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
this method is not calling for me when i tap on the cover..Can u please tell me y?

Comment: Have a look at the "Buttons Demo" example included with the library and see if you can see anything you are doing differently.

Comment: It looks like you are actually using quite an old version anyway, or you may have followed an out of date tutorial. Download the latest version from github and check the examples because some of the method names have now changed.

Comment: I have written [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; this staement but - (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender method is not calling..Rest of things are working fine....

Comment: I am using Liner Carousel and implemented delete functionalty .I am able to delete the image in carousel and when I attempt to delete any other iomage in the visible screen It is moved to carousel frame and deleted.

Comment: I need to delete the image from its original position.Please see my edit

Comment: You shouldn't keep updating the same question with different information. The original answer I posted now doesn't make sense because I was answering a different question. Stack Overflow questions are intended to be a reference for other developers looking for answers. Please put your original question back and then file the new question as a separate entry on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your responce.Please find my new question in the following link,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241139/how-to-implement-delete-functionality-for-images-in-different-positions-in-icaro

Comment: Thanks. I've answered in the other thread and rolled back your question in this thread to the original.