# How to implement delete functionality for images in different positions in iCarousel iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, icarousel

I am using iCarousel as shownh [here](http://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)  with carousel type Liner Carousel and implemented delete functionalty .I am able to delete the image in carousel and when I attempt to delete any other iomage in the visible screen It is moved to carousel frame and deleted.
I need to delete the image from its original position.

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    
    carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-130,300, 320, 100)];
    carousel.dataSource = self;
    carousel.delegate=self;
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel.scrollEnabled=YES;

    imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 50, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
    { 

    UIImage *image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 60, 60); 
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag=index;
    NSLog(@"tag is %d",button.tag);
        
    UIButton *deleteButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    deleteButton.frame= CGRectMake(50, -5, 20 ,20);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"];
    [deleteButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addSubview:deleteButton];
        
    return button;
}

-(void)deleteButtonClicked:(int )sender
{
    NSInteger currentIndex = carousel.currentItemIndex;
    [carousel removeItemAtIndex:currentIndex animated:YES];
   
}
```

Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: delete from the array? and what do you mean by  delete the image from its original position.

Comment: - (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel 
{
    return NO;
}
I am already using this in my code

Comment: IT should delete when it is in its current position..But with my code it is scrolled to caroselframe position.

Comment: Simply I able to edit or delete the image which is in firstposition of my visible screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't delete the item at the carousel.currentItemIndex because that is not the item corresponding to the button you clicked, that's just the currently centred item in the carousel.

To get the correct item index for the button you clicked, do this:

```
-(void)deleteButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    //get the index of the item view containing the button that was clicked
    NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemViewOrSubview:sender];

    //update the data model (always do this first)
    [imagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];

    //remove item from carousel
    [carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I am getting these warnings  warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') with an expression of type 'id' [3]
warning: instance method '-indexOfitemViewOrSubview:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [3] and my app is crashed..

Comment: Your sender parameter needs to be of type id, not of type int as it was in your original code. indexOfitemViewOrSubview should have a capital "i" after "Of" - that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
    [carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
    [imagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

add this also:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{    
    if (self) {
        //set up carousel data
         wrap = NO;
    }
}
```

or make your

`carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCustom;`

to

`carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;`

then implement this: `[carousel reloadData];`

Comment: Please check my edit.I f I attemt to delete image1,It is getting deleted,When I try to delete 4th image(image need to delete)in screen shot, it is scrolled to first image position.

Comment: you want to delete it an retain its position? its automatically reposition when you delete an item in `iCarousel`.

Comment: wrap = NO; here I am getting errror, use of undeclared identifier wrap

Comment: `@property (nonatomic) BOOL wrap;` in your .h   then synthesize it your .m.

Comment: Sorry No use,When I touch the image,It is scrolled to carousel frame position,there I can delete..